# is there anyway to connect to sybase from c# without having to add a ODBC DSN connection in control panel

Tags: c#, connection-string, sybase

I am looking for a way to connect to sybase from C# without having to setup an ODBC DSN connection locally on the machine.

Is this possible? I tried all of these different connection strings:

```
static private DataTable Run(string sql)
{
    var conn = new OdbcConnection();

    const string CONN_STRING2 =
        "Data Source='[myServer]';Port=5020;Database=[dbName];Uid=[user];Pwd=[pwd];";

    const string CONN_STRING1 =
        "Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;Server Name=[myServer];Server Port Address=5020;Initial Catalog=[dbName];User ID=[user];Password=[pwd];";

    conn.Open();

    var da = new OdbcDataAdapter { SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand() };
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = sql;
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    da.Dispose();
    conn.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

But I got an error stating:

> {"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}

Comment: I think you need to post more code, where are you creating the connection, and assigning the connection string to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `var conn = new OdbcConnection()`.  That is why you are getting the error.

You will need to use a sybase oledb client library.  I don't know sybase at all but last I heard one needed to purchase a third-party provider.  This was almost three years ago so they may have one by now.

You would then need to do something like `var connection = new ASEConnection()`.

Answer (score 1):

Download the DLL from the following link:

[Sybase library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sybase.AdoNet.AseClient.dll/)

Use this library for connection:

```
ASEconnection connection = new AseConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use specific ADO.Net data provider [stright from manufacturer](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_ASE_SDK/) (SAP now own sybase). I think you can manage to create a connection string yourself using [this reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/advantage-net-data-provider/). For [example](https://help.sap.com/viewer/54c3945e6dd14033889f875bed1323ce/16.0.3.5/en-US/b1745db8bbf910148b75d8c792ace999.html):

```
var connStr = @"Data Source=\\myserver\myvolume\mypat\mydd.add;User ID=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;ServerType=REMOTE;"
using (ASEConnection conn = new AseConnection(connStr)) {
    // use conn
}
```

Same informaton can be obtained from documentation mentioned earlier.